# Accessing Calendar Information from Exchange 2003 using c# .NET

Tags: asp.net, calendar, exchange-server

I am trying to create a booking system in C#.NET that will store bookings within a MSQL database but also add the bookings to the exchange calendar of the relevant user.

When a new appointment is created I want it to check the availabiity of users with their exchange calendars. If they are available it will book a date in the .NET system and also add an entry to exchange.

Is it possible to integrate .NET with exchange 2003?

The system would need to access 5 users calendar's and find their availability, could it be setup to allow this using a system user account or a new account created for this purpose?

Comment: I would suggest to upgrade Exchange from 2003 to 2007SP1 or 2010 so you can use Exchange Web Services Managed API. It's that good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this successfully with Exchange 2007 using the Exchange Web Services, which a quick search on google suggests they are available in Exchange 2003.

You have to install/enable the web services, setup an account in exchange that has  impersonation rights on the other users.

Then you connect to the web service using a service binding that uses those master credentials and impersonates the other user. I found all the examples I needed in the MSDN site.

Update: Looks like the services I am talking about were introduced with 2007, sorry.

Comment: i got excited for a minute then :(